# HD5770 cannot detect third monitor

Tags: graphics-card, dvi, displayport, eyefinity

I an XFX HD5770 graphics card with two DVI ports, one HDMI, and one DP. To use Eyefinity with three monitors I want to use two DVI ports and the DP. (**Active** display port is required for this).

I bought an active displayPort to single-link DVI adapter from Sapphire.

However my computer can't detect the third monitor connected to the display port with an active DP to single-link DVI. The other two monitors connected to the DVI port work correctly.

How do I solve this?

Comment: WHat ports does your grapics card have? Your question seems to imply 2xdvi + DP. To me, the most common seems to be VGA+DVI+HDMI.

Comment: @fstx if you look up the model he listed in the OP, you will see the series of graphics cards include 2xDVI, 1xHDMI and 1xDP.

Answer (score 1):

What Operating System are you running this on? Have you updated your graphics drivers? Assuming Windows, have you ran Windows Update to get all the updates available? Have you updated DirectX any time recently?

One other thing to do is try this:

1) Turn the computer off.

2) Disconnect ALL the monitors except the one connected to the DP port.

3) Turn the computer on

If (You get video from the monitor)
Then (Your graphics card is functioning properly, the issue likely lies in Windows/Software/Your OS)

Else, If (You get no video from the monitor)
Then (Your cable is no good, your monitor is no good, or your graphics card/port is no good)

EOF

Comment: +!. If the DisplayPort-connected display is working, the eyefinity group has to be set up through `Catalyst Control Center -> Desktop Management -> Creating and Arranging Desktops` as well, and Windows cloning/spanning has to be disabled.

Comment: The Catalyst center, only detect the 2 DVI-Conected Monitors, but not the Monitor conected to the display port. The monitor is not the problem, (the tree monitores are the same, LG E2360V News, the cable is Sapphire, the DP Port of the target never used. When i conect only the monitor, i dont get video from the monitor. (The drivers are up to date, windows 7 and Video Card)

Comment: @Nicolas Ceroni so to recap. If you have ONLY the monitor connected through DP connected to your computer after you turn it on, and you do not connect another monitor at all and you get no video, then your cable is damaged or your graphics card is damaged/experiencing a manufacturer's defect (port is dead).

Comment: If the port is damaged, can be fixed?

Comment: @Nicolas Ceroni it would be too costly to fix (outside of a factory), if it is faulty you need to RMA it if you are under warranty, if you are not under warranty you will need to replace it.

Comment: @Bloodylron Replace the video Card?, i'm From Chile...

Comment: @Nicolas Ceroni if it is under warranty, and the manufacturer honours it, then it will only cost you shipping the card to the factory to get it repaired. If it is not under warranty, then you will not be able to find a location to repair it, and if you want 3 monitors working in such a situation, you will need too _buy a new graphics card_.

Comment: @BloodyIron thanks, today i try the cable whit a similar videocard (HD5770 of Saphire) and then i can know what hapen.

Answer (score 0):

Here a [few notes about using Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5770/pages/ati-radeon-hd-5770-overview.aspx#5) with that card:

> Driver version 8.66 (Catalyst 9.10) or above is required to support ATI Eyefinity technology and to enable a third display you require one panel with a DisplayPort connector.
>
> ATI Eyefinity technology works with games that support non-standard aspect ratios which is required for panning across three displays.

So check those drivers, and make sure its up to date.

Comment: The drivers was up to date, (24 april 2012), Windows are up to date (Windows 7), When i start te computer, with only monitor conected to DP (With the adapter), the monitor dont show any image, isn¿t detected for the computer.

Comment: @Nicolas the adapter you got may be broken

Comment: I've had at least one DisplayPort/DVI active adapter break. If you just connect one monitor, I think you should not need an active adapter, just a DP/DVI cable. If you can try that you can see if it is your adapter or your graphics card.